# CUPS problem - prints everything three times

Tags: 22.04, printing

Hope this isn't a dumb question...I am running 22.04 LTS, fully updated, with CUPS 2.4.1 on this machine.  My home network server is on Debian 11, and also has CUPS installed.  When I print a job from any of my Linux machines (most of my network machines are on Ubuntu or Debian), it prints the entire job three times (happens with both network printers). If I boot one of my multi-OS boxes to Windows or MacOS, only one copy is printed.  I found an OLD (2017) bug report on this was resolved by downgrading then upgrading, and the bug was closed.  Has anyone else had this happen?  I have been running Linux since the Slackware days and have never had this happen before.  I have always had CUPS on both the network server and the clients.  Is there something I need to change?  Thanks in advance.